# How to determine optimal number of cluster in Jenks Natural Breaks

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am using Jenks Natural Breaks in R to conduct clustering on a large data set that consists of 60000 data points. Typically k-means uses elbow method.
How can I apply elbow-method on Jenks to determine the no. of optimal clusters?

Answer (score 0):

We use an example from BAMMtools:

```
library(BAMMtools)
data(whales, events.whales)
ed <- getEventData(whales, events.whales, burnin=0.25, nsamples=500)

ed <- dtRates(ed, tau=0.01)
vec <- ed$dtrates$rates[[1]]
```

You can calculate the total withinss once you know the groups. I use the anova function in R to calculate this:

```
cal_wss = function(values,group){
                  if(is.numeric(group)){
                         group = factor(group)
                  }
                  sum((aov(values ~ group)$residuals^2))
                  }

kmeans3 = kmeans(vec,3,nstart=100)

kmeans3$tot.withinss
[1] 0.4228335

cal_wss(vec,kmeans3$cluster)
[1] 0.4228335
```

So we can see the function gives the same result as kmeans internal calculation. Now we run it for different k values in kmeans and Jenk Natural Break:

```
kmeans_withinss = sapply(2:10,function(i)kmeans(vec,i,nstart=100)$tot.withinss)

j_withinss = sapply(2:10,function(i){
                    Jenk = getJenksBreaks(vec,i+1)
                    clus = cut(vec,breaks=Jenk,include.lowest =TRUE)
                    cal_wss(vec,clus)
                   })

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(2:10,kmeans_withinss,xlab="k",ylab="within ss",main="kmeans")

plot(2:10,j_withinss,xlab="k",ylab="within ss",main="Jenk")
```

[image]